# How to get merkle proofs for data stored on chain?

Tags: solana-program, data, verify, verification

I am creating an application on solana and I would like merkle proofs for my data like other blockchains.
https://docs.solana.com/proposals/simple-payment-and-state-verification - this is the most I could find - any suggestions?

Comment: I could also get to the same thing. 
basically what i think the problem is that Solana Block Headers are entry Ids and consist of the transaction hash which in-turn in the first signature of the transaction.